# 301 not issued automatically in Magento

Tags: php, magento, redirect

I see that if the name of a product is changed in my Magento V 1.9.2.2 shop, links from google are giving 404's for the url's with the old name instead of redirecting to the new page and getting a 301.

I know I can manually add the redirect in the URL Rewrite
Maintenance section and that does work but I'm wondering if that is how Magento works or if I am missing something? If it is how it works, it seems a big oversight on Magento's part.

Is there a known fix for this or maybe some setting I have to change? Or do I need to enter such changes in manually each time?

Answer (score 0):

For create new URL Rewrite magento have **Catalog URL Rewrites** indexing. So when you did Catalog URL Rewrites indexing then all the URL generate properly. Have you try to indexing? Also check its on ready state or not.

Comment: I appreciate your reply but I don't  understand it. Should the Catalog-> URL Rewrite  section be updated automatically when a name is changed or do I have to enter in each change manually? Please explain what "try to indexing" and "check its on ready state" mean.